# How would I refactor my code to stop passing a class object everywhere?

Tags: vb.net, refactoring

I am currently working on improving the design of an insurance quote engine. There is no design documentation but it involves passing in a 'QuoteData' class object into almost every sub, and because of that design choice the object has to have a number of its variables 'reset' so that it doesn't accidentally carry over into other scheme-specific code blocks.

After processing its input data it calls out to each scheme engine block, for example:

PcEngine:

```
Call Engine201611Pc71(pobjQuote)
```

Engine201611Pc71:

```
Call Scheme1(pobjQuote)
```

Scheme1:

```
Call AreaRating(pobjQuote)
Call VehicleGroupRating(pobjQuote)
Call CheckOutEachDriver(pobjQuote)
```

It should be noted there are several scheme subs, each with over a dozen other sub calls related to its scheme rules.

Ideally I would want to have a QuoteData instance for each scheme quote but we're reusing the same one for everything; that's thousands of scheme quotes with just one instance of QuoteData.

How would I go about refactoring? Originally it was a struct being passed ByRef everywhere (with 1000+ members)!

Comment: This is braud. We don't know the use of the object and the functions. Maybe it's ok. Maybe these functions should be in the class, maybe the object should be split into multiple object. Just by the information we have, there is nothing wrong in passing an object to multiple methods.

Comment: Agree w/@the_lotus but examine every one of the methods which need that object passed and see whether it makes sense to make it a method.  `VehicleGroupRating` for instance sounds like it could be a method: `myQuote.RateVehicles`.  `A class named `QuoteData` sounds like it maybe should be a private internal class named `Quote` where all the Quote related logic and rules reside and it acts on that data class

Comment: I had originally thought passing one instance of a QuoteData object for potentially thousands of quotes, resetting each time, sounded strange. I guess I was off the mark after all. Thanks.